Why is my gov.uk IHS surcharge payment repeatedly declined?
I am trying to pay for the IHS Surcharge for a student visa but the payment continues to say it’s declined. However I have enough funds on the card and have tried different cards with the same result. Does anyone know what I should do?

A family member had the same issue in the same circumstances. He resolved it by calling the issuing bank and keeping them on the line while he re-submitted; the bank staff member was able to ensure that the payment went through.
